# Blackberry application development setup for mac issue...?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, blackberry, installation

I'm new to blackberry mobile application development. I'm using mac as os and eclipse juno. Just download **BlackBerry Java Plug-in Setup** from https://developer.blackberry.com/java/download/eclipse

when I try to install it, it gives me below warning
[image]

when I go with the link **BlackBerry Desktop Software for Mac** http://us.blackberry.com/404.html. No page available there.

Anyone facing the same issue. What should I do.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer

link embed **BlackBerry Desktop Software for Mac** is dead. It replace by below one. And actually it is for mac you have to download and install before installing **BlackBerry Java Plug-in Setup**
http://us.blackberry.com/software/desktop/desktop-mac.html

Comment: You can **accept** your own answer, and should do so ... that way we know that this problem is solved.  Thanks.